# how does a JSP access or mutate a session bean with EL? (MVC)

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, jstl, el

Right now the controller servlet seems to handle dispatching correctly, so far as I can tell, in that it dispatches to a specified JSP.  It uses an instance of `MyToken`, kept in the session, to track the session.  The controller dispatches to different JSP's depending on booleans of the `MyToken` instance.

I've put all the JSP's in `WEB-INF` so that only the controller servlet is exposed -- preferably, all requests/responses go through the servlet.

The intention is to use the `MyToken` object as a session bean.

How does a JSP access such a session bean with EL?  The `login.jsp` page needs set the name value for the bean, and then dispatch back to the controller.

Can that be done with EL?  Or, is it only possible to access a session bean with the JSTL?

It's intended as MVC, sans a framework -- just a very simple login with a simple bean for storing simple user data.  A properties file contains a list of valid users which the token credentials are checked against.

Controller servlet:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.servlets;

import filter.PropertiesReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/controller")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName());

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("controller processing request..");
        String jsp = dispatcherLogic(request.getSession());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/" + jsp).forward(request, response);
    }

    private String dispatcherLogic(HttpSession session) {
        Properties properties = PropertiesReader.getProps();
        MyToken token = (MyToken) session.getAttribute("token");
        if (token != null) {
            token.setAuthenticated(properties.containsValue(token.getName()));
        } else {
            token = new MyToken();
        }
        log.info(token.toString());
        session.setAttribute("token", token);
        if (token.isAuthenticated()) {
            return "success.jsp";
        } else {
            if (token.isAttemptedLogin()) {
                return "fail.jsp";
            } else {
                return "login.jsp";
            }
        }
    }

    private String dispatcherLogic0(HttpSession session) {
        Map<String, String> p = PropertiesReader.getPropsAsMap();
        Enumeration<String> names = session.getAttributeNames();
        for (String s : Collections.list(names)) {
            log.info(s);
        }
        MyToken t = (MyToken) session.getAttribute("token");
        for (String s : p.keySet()) {
            //  t.getName() = p.containsValue(s);
        }
        return "hello.jsp";  //always to hello page for now
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "controller";
    }
}


<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="bar" action="controller" method="POST">
            name <input type="text" name="username" value="Jim" size='20' />
            <p>
                <input type="submit">
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>AuthenticateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filter.AuthenticateFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>Name</param-name>
            <param-value>Value</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthenticateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/foo.jsp</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <description>all</description>
            <display-name>all</display-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

token for login credentials:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.servlets;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MyToken {//should probably be immutable...

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyToken.class.getName());

    private String name = "nemo";
    private String role = "captain";
    private String password = "abc";
    private boolean authenticated = false;  //remove down the road?
    private boolean attemptedLogin = false;  //remove down the road?

    public MyToken() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return authenticated;
    }

    public void setAuthenticated(boolean authenticated) {
        this.authenticated = authenticated;
    }

    public boolean isAttemptedLogin() {
        return attemptedLogin;
    }

    public void setAttemptedLogin(boolean attemptedLogin) {
        this.attemptedLogin = attemptedLogin;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + authenticated + attemptedLogin;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can access you session beans name simply by

```
${sessionScope.token.name}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaim.html